# Change Detection on ngIf causing exception

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I've got an issue with change detection that I'm not exactly sure what to do to fix.

```
    CEChats.find({
        group: {$in: groupIds},
    })
    .map((sub2: any) => {
      sub2.forEach((chat)=> {
          this.findLastChatMessage(chat._id, chat.lastMessage).subscribe(lmsgsub=> {
            chat.lastMessage = lmsgsub;
            chat.unseen = !chat.lastMessage.seenBy.some((x)=>x==this.user._id);
            this.appRef.tick();
          });
      });
      this.groupChats = sub2;
      this.appRef.tick();
    });
```

I'm doing this call in a shared service component.
(no @component or @page)

The groupChats is used in another component (chatList) which uses the unseen key on an `*ngIf` to show/hide an icon

```
<ion-icon name="radio-button-on" *ngIf="chat.unseen"></ion-icon>
```

When I change to the child page (chat) of chatList, I get 
`"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'."`

changing the changeDetection to onPush didn't help, and I cant use `changeDetectorRef` in the service as it come up with no provider available (because it isn't a component?)

I also tried using `ApplicationRef.tick()` which also didn't help.
I used the appilcationRef inside both the internal subscription (`lastMessage`) and the setting of the `groupChats`. Neither helped.

The update that causes the value to change is done in the child Chat page when it pulls the collection of messages.

The app updates each message that hasn't been seen before with the users ID, (as a read receipt) which in turn causes the subscription above to update (`findLastMessage()`)

I'm using Ionic with angular-meteor for this.

Comment: ApplicationRef.tick() causes change detection to fire, so maybe if I add changeDetectionStrategy.onPush to the chatList page it will work. Not tried yet, will update when I five it a go

Comment: It didn't seem to help.  I've refactored my code to use an observable subscription better which seems to be working. I'll post what I did as an answer in the morning